# Is it possible to add a render texture to a gameObject through a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What Ive been trying to do is create a camera, a cube, and take what the camera sees and display it on the cube. I would like to do all of this through a single script, where I instantiate a cube and camera prefab, and from there I do the connection between the two.

So far, Ive managed to create both of these objects, and Ive created a render texture, which is assigned to the camera:

```
GameObject cubo = Instantiate(cuboprefab);
            GameObject camara = Instantiate(prefabCamara);
            cubo.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            camara.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 3);
            rt = new RenderTexture(256, 256, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
            rt.useDynamicScale = true;
            rt.Create(); 
            var compcam = camara.GetComponent<Camera>();
            compcam.targetTexture = rt;
            //cubo.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = rt;
```

The last line is commented because thats where my issue is, I cant seem to find a way to assign a RenderTexture object to the material, even though it is something that you can do with the Unity UI.

Comment: The behavior you are describing is more complicated than you might think. Simply slapping a render texture onto the cube would waste valuable performance, as not all pixels would always be visible from a far distance or off screen. The usual approach would be to use shaders to “redirect” the rays cast by the camera so that you are not having a huge performance hit, but this is complicated. I would recommend following a tutorial online, a search query could be like “unity portals guide”

Comment: RenderTexture is a Texture, but you're trying to assign it to a Material field.  You need  to first apply the texture to a material, and then assign that material to the renderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently trying to assign a material, not the texture of the material.  Set the texture to the `mainTexture` property of the material instead.

```
cubo.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.mainTexture = rt;
```